# Google Maps Places autocomplete fills incorrectly when back button used

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a simple address form for an address  When I continue to next page and then click the back button, the address data is messed up. The address is missing, address2 field has the city, city field has the zip and the zip is missing...

[image: Address Form before] 
[image: Address Form after clicking back button.]

If I remove the google maps script at the bottom, everything works fine, but including it, I get the erroneous behavior.  I've made the autocomplete as simple as possible and have even removed the fillInAddress() piece for the autocomplete. Not sure where to go from here. Any help is appreciated.

```
[![<script src="../assets/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
{% block content %}
    <div class="customer js-cart-form-step js-form-wrap col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6">
        <h5>Customer Information</h5>
        <div class="email row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="moving-input input-required input-email">
                    <input class="stripspaces" type="text" id="shipping_email" autocapitalize="off" value="{{ lead.email }}" autocomplete="on">
                    <label>Email</label>    
                </div>                              
            </div>
        </div>
        <h5>Shipping Address</h5>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                <div class="moving-input input-required input-firstname">
                    <input type="text" id="shipping_first_name" value="{{ lead.firstname }}"  autocomplete="on">
                    <label>First Name</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                <div class="moving-input input-required input-lastname">
                    <input type="text" id="shipping_last_name" autocomplete="on">
                    <label>Last Name</label>    
                </div>                                  
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                <div class="moving-input input-required input-address">
                    <input type="text" id="shipping_address" class="route street_number" placeholder="" autocomplete="on" >
                    <label>Address</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                <div class="moving-input">                          
                    <input type="text" id="shipping_address2" autocomplete="on">
                    <label>Apartment/Suite #</label>        
                </div>                              
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                <div class="moving-input  input-required input-city">
                    <input type="text" id="shipping_city" class="locality" autocomplete="on">
                    <label>City</label> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="shipping_state_input" class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                <div class="moving-input js-location-picker input-required">
                    <select id="shipping_state">
                        <option></option>
                        <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
                        <option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
                        <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
                        <option value="Arkansas">Arkansas</option>
                        <option value="California">California</option>
                        <option value="Colorado">Colorado</option>
                        <option value="Connecticut">Connecticut</option>
                        <option value="Delaware">Delaware</option>
                        <option value="District of Columbia">District of Columbia</option>
                        <option value="Florida">Florida</option>
                        <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
                        <option value="Hawaii">Hawaii</option>
                        <option value="Idaho">Idaho</option>
                        <option value="Illinois">Illinois</option>
                        <option value="Indiana">Indiana</option>
                        <option value="Iowa">Iowa</option>
                        <option value="Kansas">Kansas</option>
                        <option value="Kentucky">Kentucky</option>
                        <option value="Louisiana">Louisiana</option>
                        <option value="Maine">Maine</option>
                        <option value="Maryland">Maryland</option>
                        <option value="Massachusetts">Massachusetts</option>
                        <option value="Michigan">Michigan</option>
                        <option value="Minnesota">Minnesota</option>
                        <option value="Mississippi">Mississippi</option>
                        <option value="Missouri">Missouri</option>
                        <option value="Montana">Montana</option>
                        <option value="Nebraska">Nebraska</option>
                        <option value="Nevada">Nevada</option>
                        <option value="New Hampshire">New Hampshire</option>
                        <option value="New Jersey">New Jersey</option>
                        <option value="New Mexico">New Mexico</option>
                        <option value="New York">New York</option>
                        <option value="North Carolina">North Carolina</option>
                        <option value="North Dakota">North Dakota</option>
                        <option value="Ohio">Ohio</option>
                        <option value="Oklahoma">Oklahoma</option>
                        <option value="Oregon">Oregon</option>
                        <option value="Pennsylvania">Pennsylvania</option>
                        <option value="Rhode Island">Rhode Island</option>
                        <option value="South Carolina">South Carolina</option>
                        <option value="South Dakota">South Dakota</option>
                        <option value="Tennessee">Tennessee</option>
                        <option value="Texas">Texas</option>
                        <option value="Utah">Utah</option>
                        <option value="Vermont">Vermont</option>
                        <option value="Virginia">Virginia</option>
                        <option value="Washington">Washington</option>
                        <option value="West Virginia">West Virginia</option>
                        <option value="Wisconsin">Wisconsin</option>
                        <option value="Wyoming">Wyoming</option>
                    </select>
                    <label>State</label>        
                </div>                              
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">    
                <div class="moving-input input-required input-zip-code">    
                    <label>Zip</label>
                    <input type="text" id="shipping_zip" class="postal_code" maxlength="5"  autocomplete="on" class="prep">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">    
                <div class="moving-input input-required input-phone">                               
                    <input id="shipping_phone" value="{{ lead.phone }}"  maxlength="10" autocomplete="on"  type="tel" pattern="\[0-9\]*" inputmode="numeric">
                    <label>Phone</label>
                </div>                                  
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-message-error js-form-message-error col-xs-12">
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <button class="btn btn-dark js-button-customer" tabindex="12">continue</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}
    <script>

    function saveCustomerInfo(dto) {
        $.ajax("/api/saveCustomerInfo", {
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            data: { lead: dto },
            type: "POST",
            success: function(result, status, xhr) {
                if (result.ok !== true) {
                    console.log("FAIL saveCustomerInfo: " + result.debug);
                    Rollbar.error("API call to saveCustomerIfo failed",{debug: result.debug});
                } else {
                    window.location.href = "/checkout/shipping";
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                displayGenericError();
            }
        });
    };

    function saveLead(email) {
        var dto = {
            email: email
        };
        if (navigator.sendBeacon) {
            navigator.sendBeacon("/api/saveLead",JSON.stringify(dto));
        } else {
            $.post("/api/saveLead", dto);
        }
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {


        $('.js-button-customer').click(function(event) {

            var state_val = $('#shipping_state option:selected').text();

            $('.form-message-error p').text('');

            //var form_valid = validate_form($(this).closest('.js-form-wrap'));
            if (true) {
                var dto = {
                    firstname: $('#shipping_first_name').val().trim(),
                    lastname: $('#shipping_last_name').val().trim(),
                    email: $('#shipping_email').val().trim().toLowerCase(),
                    phone: $('#shipping_phone').val(),
                    address1: $('#shipping_address').val(),
                    address2: $('#shipping_address2').val(),
                    city: $('#shipping_city').val(),
                    state: state_val,
                    postalCode: $('#shipping_zip').val()            
                };
                saveCustomerInfo(dto);
            } else {

                $('.form-message-error').slideDown(400);
                $('.input-required input, textarea').focus(function() {
                    $('.form-message-error').slideUp(400);
                    $('.form-message-error p').text('');
                });
                var e = form_valid.errormsgs;
                var em = e.join('<br/>');
                $('.form-message-error p').append(em);

                event.preventDefault(); // stop if invalid
            };
        });
    });

    $('.summary-footer-desktop').hide();
    </script>

    <script>

    function initAutocomplete() {
      // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
      // location types.
       autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
           /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('shipping_address')),
           {});

      // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
      // fields in the form.
      //autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
    }
  </script>


    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={{config.GoogleAPIKey}}&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
{% endblock %}][1]][1]
```

Comment: Is this in the Chrome browser?

Comment: Yes, it does appear to be only in chrome. I just tried in Firefox and Edge and it appears to be working correctly.